# Datalog maintaining views incrementally with negation

Tags: database-theory, datalog

Given a single IDB rule

$$R(x) \ \mathop{:\!\!-}  \  A(x), \lnot B(x)$$

Where $A$ and $B$ are EDB predicates, how would I go about calculating changes to $R$ as tuples are added to $B$? As I understand, when tuples are added to $B$, tuples may need to be removed from $R$.

[This paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/213883593_Maintaining_views_incrementally) says

> We present the DRed algorithm to incrementally maintain recursive views that use negation

and

> A semi-naive computation is sufficient to compute new inserted tuples
>   for a recursively defined view when insertions are made to base
>   relations.

The DRed algorithm seems to take an input of the deleted EDB tuples, so adding a new tuple (and starting with a null set for deleted tuples) would have no effect. Have I missed something here?

Perhaps I misunderstand the definition of stratified negation, is $R$ an invalid rule?